# How to see free disk space on SunOS?

Tags: solaris, hard-disk, disk-usage

It really makes me mad.
SunOS 5.9

```
#format 
Searching for disks...done
No disks found!
# mount
/ on /dev/md/dsk/d0...(skip)
/var on /dev/md/dsk/d4 ...
/opt on /dev/md/dsk/d5 ...
/home on /dev/md/dsk/d9 ...
/usr/local on /dev/md/dsk/d10 ...
# fdisk -G /dev/md/dsk/d0
fdisk: /dev/md/dsk/d0 must be a raw device.
# fdisk -G /dev/md/dsk
fdisk: /dev/md/dsk must be a raw device.
# fdisk -G  /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0 
fdisk: Cannot open device /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0.
# ls /dev/rdsk
c0t0d0s0   c0t0d0s6  ...(72 items total)
# ls /dev/md/
admin   dsk     rdsk    shared
# ls /dev/md/dsk
d0......d127
```

prtvtoc works, but I can see total space only and have to use calculator to get Mb/Gb :(

```
# prtvtoc /dev/md/dsk/d10
* /dev/md/dsk/d10 partition map
*
* Dimensions:
*     512 bytes/sector
*     424 sectors/track
*      24 tracks/cylinder
*   10176 sectors/cylinder
*   14087 cylinders
*   14087 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
       0      0    00          0 143349312 143349311
# prtvtoc -f /dev/md/dsk/d0
FREE_START=0 FREE_SIZE=0 FREE_COUNT=0 FREE_PART=
```

Regardless FREE_SIZE=0 system is up and running quite well.
moreover:

```
# df
df: cannot execute
# bdf
bdf: not found
# pkgadd
pkgadd: not found
```

Please help.

P.S. this server is really in bad condition:

```
# ls /
(here some folders, including usr)
# ls /usr
(here some folders again, including apache)
#ls /usr/apache
/usr/apache: I/O error
```

Thanks @Nikhil and @MaxMackie. I think the trouble is out of this question.

Comment: Which version of Solaris are you using? Which shell are you using? df execution failure ccertainly raises eye brows. Would you check your path and execute the commands directly from their path.

Comment: metastat would give you the state of the metadb replication, running `df -h -T ufs` would give you the status of free space on prior to Solaris-10 or non-zfs local filesystems. ZFS filesystems however, would be better off using zfs commands like `zpool` and `zfs`

Comment: Maybe here is really no free space:  
    # /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S  
    Bus Error  
    # find  
    find: cannot execute  
@Nikhil I just tried this:  
    # /bin/df  
    /bin/df: cannot execute

Comment: @Nikhil
# df -h -T ufs
df: cannot execute
        # zpool  
        zpool: not found  
        # zfs  
zfs: not found  
    Unfortunately I can't get linebreak in comment :(

Comment: Another question now that you have told me it is Solaris 9. Is it sparc or x86? zpool and zfs commands are only available in Solaris 10 some later versions and thereafter in Solaris 11. Okay, I see the machine has not booted properly. You may confirm the runlevel with `who -r` on the prompt.

Comment: `prtvtoc` shows no partitions on your hdd. Have you got your OS installed properly at all?

Comment: At this juncture, only `format` command seems to be working for you, for seeing free disk space but albeit with no luck, it does not detect the disks for you -- that is the problem. What is the hardware you are running on?

Comment: @Nikhil it's sparc. Sorry for no linebreaks:# who -r (\n)
   .       run-level 3  Jul 22 10:57     3      0  S (\n)
I did all these things as root.

# psrinfo -v(\n)
Status of virtual processor 0 as of: 12/08/2011 11:10:42
  on-line since 07/22/2010 10:56:52.
  The sparcv9 processor operates at 1280 MHz,
        and has a sparcv9 floating point processor.(\n)
Status of virtual processor 1 as of: 12/08/2011 11:10:42
  on-line since 07/22/2010 10:56:50.
  The sparcv9 processor operates at 1280 MHz,
        and has a sparcv9 floating point processor.(\n)

Comment: @Nikhil
# uname -a(\n)
SunOS traynor 5.9 Generic_122300-30 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V250(\n)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1943/discussion-between-nikhil-and-putnik)

Comment: Putnik, I am available on chat. let me see if I can find any pointers for you in the meanwhile..get into chat if you are seeing this(while I can be there in next 15-20mins)

Comment: is this a new (re)installation or attempt of fix of the previously installed but now garbled state OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as `df` doesn't seem to be working for you, try running this in the root directory of the mounted filesystem/disk. In my case, I'd like to see the total amount of space used by my OS hard drive and ignore all of my mounted file systems. Ran from `/`:

```
max@linux-vwzy:/> sudo du -h -d0 -x ./ 2> /dev/null
23G     ./
```

So my OS takes up 23GB. Of course this only works if you know the size of your disk. If I also index other filesystems & disks:

```
max@linux-vwzy:/> sudo du -h -d0 ./ 2> /dev/null
2.6T    ./
```

Hope that helps. It's not the best method but it just might work for you.

Comment: :I did all these commands as a root. Sorry for no linebreaks
# cd / (\n)
# du -h -d0 -x ./ 2> /dev/null (\n)
# du -h -d0 -x ./ (\n)
du: illegal option -- 0 (\n)
usage: du [-a] [-d] [-h|-k] [-r] [-o|-s] [-L] [file ...] (\n)
# sudo du -h -d0 -x ./  (\n)
sudo: not found (\n)

Comment: try this: `du -h --one-file-system --max-depth=0 ./`. Doesn't look like you have `sudo` installed and you might have another version of `du`. I'm using `du (GNU coreutils) 8.9`